# Angular 8+Ionic4 bundle everything into a single JS file during development

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, upload, http2

I would like to configure webpack and ionic4/angular to bundle everything into a single JS file. I understand that multiple js files (even if hundreds) are, somehow, good with http2. But during development, when I have to upload everything to a dev-testing-server, hundreds of generated files, take very long to upload and I want to cut those times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for if you are using Amazon Web Services(AWS),
You can use AWS CodeCommit for that, just do upload your regular code there(GIT).
Use .yml template to build automatically after your code commit push to your master branch where your .yml template trigger, and it will upload your build files to S3 automatically in just 3-4 mins.